# mPDF: Hide table row (CSS display:none) not work

Tags: php, css, mpdf

mPDF: Hide table row (CSS display:none) not work.
Do you have any suggest?
My code:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr style="display:none">
        <td valign="top" align="left">InfoOption1:</td>
        <td valign="top" align="left" colspan="2">#InfoOption1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not for me, the content appear still, also I read document they have not support css 'display' property for TR html tag. ref: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34&searchstring=display

Comment: Try visibility:hidden;

Comment: visibility also not work, I just tried.

Comment: Well, than just don't add the <tr> element

Comment: Is suitable? What if I turn TR to DIV instead even invalid rules.

Comment: Daan, you have enough reputation to know that your comments are useless like this. There could be a million reasons why "just don't add" doesn't work (like now, for me).

Answer (score 6):

I feel very dirty for posting this suggestion, but it's the best I got working:

```
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
<div style="display: none;">
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
</div>
```

The DIV is the working part. Luckily, html validnes for seo isnt relevant for mPDF

Comment: This is a good workaround but I can't use this as my HTML is not only used for mPDF, I can add classes but can't play with the DOM. Did you find another way since ? (btw I have to hide a TD, actually a column...)
Here is supported CSS : https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html
Therefore I hid the borders and hid the td content. But there is still an empty space... better than an empty visible cell

Comment: Haha this is a while ago, I don't know how to fix your case. Maybe height=0 & overflow hidden? Or a negative margin bottom

Comment: problem is more the width than the height, having it not visible is fair enough for me :) even if width is taken. But it worth trying a negative margin right. next time...

Answer (score 1):

It works if you enclose the row you want to hide inside a Div. The div will have a class which have declared hidden property.

```
<div class='hide_this_row'>
  <tr> 
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</div>

<!-- CSS file will look like this -->
<style>
  .hide_this_row{
    display :none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: `div` is the key. Doesn't have to be class, inline css will also work.